# ADO Recordset to Excel spreadsheet opens properly in Excel 2007, has a missing parameter in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, ado

My spreadsheet is reading data from another spreadsheet using ADO.  The VBA code works properly in MS Excel 2007.  However, in MS 2013, opening the recordset generates the error:  `No value given for one or more required parameters.`

The line that errors out reads:

```
recset.Open sqlCommand, _
    conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

I double checked my two variables.

- `sqlCommand` has the (sanitized) value: `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [F1] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [F1] ASC`.
- `conn` is the `Connection` object, with (sanitized) value: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\path\workbook_to_read.xlsx;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False;`

The other three parameters are ADO constants.

My best guess is that the `Provider` is for the wrong version, either of Excel or ADO.  I don't know what the correct version is, nor how to make the code work in both environments.

Edit and facepalm:
Most of the Excel files I'm reading from do not have headers for the first two fields.  THIS ONE DOES, and I had to replace `[F1]` with the correct field name.  **Please close.**

Comment: `No value given for one or more required parameters.` indicates to me that a required parameter is _missing_, not incorrectly defined. There may be a new required parameter in 2013. I'd suggest in your IDE, typing `recset.open `, then let the 2013 IDE pop-up the list of parameters. Take a good look to ensure that you've specified _all_ the required ones. If your code needs to function in 2007 & 2013, there are ways within the code to determine which version you're using so you can use the appropriate line of code on your `.Open`.

Comment: I just tested a different spreadsheet with the same automation, and it worked properly.  I'll go back to the original one and double check the `recset.open` expected parameters.

Comment: @FreeMan: The `recset.Open` statement expects the same parameters in Excel 2013 as it does in Excel 2007.  Namely: Source (SQL statement), connection, open enum, lock enum, options.

Comment: Is there a difference in _required_ vs _optional_ parameters? (I don't have 2007 or 2013 to look at, only 2010). If that's not it, I'm outta ideas.

Comment: Nope, the parameters all seem to be optional and in the same order.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because my bug was using default field names with a data file that used explicit field names.

Comment: No reason to close it. It's a valuable lesson for others. (No slight intended - if you made the mistake, others may do so as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Excel files I'm reading from do not have headers for the first two fields. THIS ONE DOES, and I had to replace `[F1]` with the correct field name.

(Answer pasted from my edit on 10 July 2015.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was looking for some answer i came up with this [Treating data as text](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/)

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;  
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

And when i run some test in `Excel` it shows this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ...  
    Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;""; ...
Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False;
```

So i think that your missing parameter must be the `Extended Properties`